# How to display a field when a media is uploaded to the media library field?

Tags: 8, forms, media, ajax

I have block settings form where I have a media library field.

```
 public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
    $user_input = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $my_field = $user_input['settings']['my_field'] ?? $this->configuration['my_field'] ?? NULL;

    $form['my_field'] = [
      '#type' => 'media_library',
      '#allowed_bundles' => ['my_bundle'],
      '#title' => $this->t('Upload'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['my_field'] ?? '',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxCallback'],
        'event' => 'updateMediaLibrarySelection'
        'wrapper' => 'test-field',
      ],
    ];

    $form['test'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'test',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="test-field">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    if (empty($my_field)) {
      $form['test']['#wrapper_attributes']['class'][] = 'visually-hidden';
    }

    return $form;
  }

  



public function ajaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
    return $form['settings']['test'];
  }
```

but my ajaxCallback method never called and the test field is always hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did with javascript because the field type `media_library` is not an actual input field.

I overrided the `setMediaUploadFieldValue` jQuery function of the `media_library_form_element` module.

```
(($, Drupal) => {
  Drupal.behaviors.VideoComponent = {
    attach: () => {
      $.fn.setMediaUploadFieldValue = (data, element) => {
        const mediaElement = document.querySelector(element);
        const currentValue = mediaElement.value;

        mediaElement.value = `${currentValue}${
          currentValue === "" ? "" : ","
        }${data}`;

        try {
          fetch(`${my_url}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
              if (result) {
                // Do something
              }
            });
        } catch (error) {
          return false;
        }
      };
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```